# How to change a dict's keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

Looking for an efficient python code to achieve the below functionality.

```
dict = {'26id%3D731014': 24711, '26id%3D731039': 24000, '26id%3D731007': 21476,
        '26id%3D731025': 20106, '26id%3D731050': 18985, '26id%3D731005': 17630}
```

and this is my expected output

```
dict = {'731014': 24711, '731039': 24000, '731007': 21476, ..., 731005': 17630}
```

Want to change key name.

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: Well obviously copying the whole dict. But where do the original keys come from?

Comment: from txt file and this dict is from counter

Comment: Please do not use `dict` for a variable name; you collide with the function by the same name.

Comment: Why can't you then not strip of the the 26id%3D while creating the dict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to create a new dictionary using your existing one:

```
{k[7:]: v for (k, v) in dict.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `partition` if your intent is to break the strings on `3D`:

```
>>> {k.partition('3D')[2]:v for k,v in di.items()}
{'731039': 24000, '731025': 20106, '731014': 24711, '731007': 21476, '731005': 17630, '731050': 18985}
```